# How to change the width to the CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the Cupertino design library for Android developing in Flutter. I want to change the width of the CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl. [This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpSIR.jpg)

```
 final Map<int, Widget> myTabs = const <int, Widget>{
   0: Text("Doctor"),
   1: Text("Pacient")
 };

CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
                   groupValue: segmentedControlGroupValue,
                   children: myTabs,
                   onValueChanged: (i){
                     setState(() {
                       segmentedControlGroupValue = i;
                     });
                   },
                 ),
```

Answer (score 9):

Wrap it in SizedBox:

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(...),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I achieved it by wrapping every `Text` widget with a Container of width `double.maxFinite`:

```
final Map<int, Widget> myTabs = const <int, Widget>{
   0: Container(width: double.maxFinite, child: Text("Doctor"),),
   1: Container(width: double.maxFinite, child: Text("Pacient"),),
 };
```

Extra tip: if you want to change the **height** of `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl`'s children (option buttons), you can set the `height` of the `Container`, or you can use `padding` property, like this:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
  width: double.maxFinite,
  child: Text("Doctor"),
);
```